# Hive command line through Cygwin select query error

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, cygwin, hive

I'm using Hadoop 2.4.0 Hortonworks

I pretty new to Hadoop and am currently using Hue/Beeswax to run my standard queries which work fine, however, I now need to start creating basic shell scripts to do slightly more complex queries.  Since I'm on a Win7 machine I've install Cygwin and using SSH to connect to a Hadoop server.  When trying a simple test query I get the following error: -

```
hive -e "select actual_date from dm.date_dim limit 10"

AccessControlException: User blah cannot submit applications to queue root.default
```

At someone's suggestion I've tried changing the queue name first: -

```
set mapred.job.queuename=foo
```

Note, that if I run the same query but select all, i.e. so no MapReduce jobs are required, the query is successful: -

```
hive -e "select * from dm.date_dim limit 10"
```

My IT dept and other internal shell script developers are being very slow to respond to this (many days) so is there anything that you can suggest I should check or try.  I was told that if changing the queue name had worked then I could've put that within my .hiverc file which I'm not sure where that is.

Is this a permissions thing?  Should I be configuring something else?

I'd appreciate any help, but be aware I'm only started learning Linux very recently so you may need to dumb down any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your organization must have specified some queues to allocate the cluster resources to multiple teams. So any query other than 'select *' wont't run if you don't specify the job queue. So while running your hive queries just add this config and your queries will run:

```
hive -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=foo -e "select actual_date from dm.date_dim limit 10"
```

Comment: Yea, when I was given access to the command line I was given no advice on any settings.  Have finally be given the following to put into a .hiverc file

    set dfs.umaskmode=002;
    set mapred.job.queue.name=foo;
    set hive.stats.autogather=false;
    set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;